# jQuery recursively find element by given index

Tags: jquery, arrays, recursion, addclass

I have a menu with nested unordered lists (ul) and I have an array that contains list items indexes, which indexes are obtained from parent's index. But I cant add class to recursive list items with jQuery.

For example:

I have an array `[1,1,0]` and with this array I have to add class to list item which contains link My Link 2, Sub Link 2 and Deep Menu 1:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">My Link 1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="">My Link 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Sub Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Deep menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Deep menu 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Deep menu 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">My Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope I can explain my problem. English is not my native language and even in my native language I cant explain my problem properly.

Comment: Why are the first two lists `0` based, while the 3rd level one is `1` based? Is that just a typo? Also, can you please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Don't you mean `[2, 2, 1]` or even `[1, 1, 0]` ?

Comment: Sorry for typo array must [1,1,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood :

```
var current = $('div.parent'), // parent of master ul
    arr = [1, 1, 0],
    yourClass = 'myclass';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // we add +1 because nth-child is 1,n based, not 0,n
    current = current.find('>ul>li:nth-child(' + (arr[i] + 1) + ')');
    if (current.length === 0) break;

    current.addClass(yourClass);
}
```

This will add the class to the `<li />` tag, if you prefer to set it to the `<a />`, just do a `current.find('a').addClass('yourClass');` instead of `current.addClass(yourClass);`.